# How to detect horizontal swipe gesture on the custom UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I created custom UIScrollView and add UIImageView.
I want to detect horizontal swipe gesture on the UIScrollView, but I cannot do it.
I cannot find any other references in my case.
I found only following url, but it's not real detecting gesture.
[How to recognize swipe gesture in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648967/how-to-recognize-swipe-gesture-in-uiscrollview)
I've not any zoom effect.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't one of the [UIScrollViewDelegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) such as [UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:] work for you? I don't know your specific case, but standard way of detecting swipe action in UIScrollView should be through its delegate.