# iphone development: swipe recogniser on a scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, swipe

In my app I have a swipe gesture recogniser on my background scroller for the up direction but somehow it does not work. Here is my code below

It is in viewDidLoad

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *Swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
Swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[backgroundScroller addGestureRecognizer:Swipe];
```

and it is the SwipeRecognizer:

```
- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
        NSLog(@" *** SWIPE UP ***");
    }
}
```

However I cant have any log. Am I missing something? Thanks.

**EDIT: I found the problem. when I said scrolling is not enabled, I can recognise the gesture. But I need to to scrolling and gesture recognition simultaneously. isn't it possible?**

Answer (score 0):

Have u registered UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h file like this:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Also

```
-(void)SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{
  if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
    NSLog(@" *** SWIPE UP ***");
  }
}
```

Comment: debug and check method is called

Comment: I tried it. Yes it the problem. somehow the method is not calling but I have no idea why? :/

Comment: what contains in your scrollview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648967/how-to-recognize-swipe-gesture-in-uiscrollview

Comment: make userInteraction enabled to YES for ImageView

Comment: I found the problem and edited my question but cannot solve it. It is something like mentioned in the link you gave but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. If you don't get any `NSLog(@" *** SwipeRecognizer ***")` out put then i think you didnt tuch on SwipeRecognizer.

```
- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
 NSLog(@" *** SwipeRecognizer ***");
if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
    NSLog(@" *** SWIPE UP ***");
}
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: No still I do not get any log.