# iOS card swipe animation & scroll view

Tags: ios, iphone

I am implementing an iPhone application in which I am trying to build the feature which is the combination of Card swipe (Same like Tinder) & scroll effect. Please have look following detailed information.

When user open the application, then it shows other user profile. So logged in user can swipe a card left (nope) or right (like)and that card will be removed from the list and the next user card will be appear. Now if user does not want to swipe the card, then he can do scroll up or down to view the other user profile.

So, is it possible to implement combination of card swipe & scroll feature.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a bit old by now, but **yes**, this is exactly what I've been building for the last few months.

I basically added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to a `UICollectionView` with a custom flowlayout (for card paging etc).

This is what it looks like:

[image: example]

Main component logic:

```
import Foundation

/**
 The VerticalCardSwiper is a subclass of `UIView` that has a `VerticalCardSwiperView` embedded.

 To use this, you need to implement the `VerticalCardSwiperDatasource`.

 If you want to handle actions like cards being swiped away, implement the `VerticalCardSwiperDelegate`.
 */
public class VerticalCardSwiper: UIView {

    /// The collectionView where all the magic happens.
    public var verticalCardSwiperView: VerticalCardSwiperView!

    /// Indicates if side swiping on cards is enabled. Default value is `true`.
    @IBInspectable public var isSideSwipingEnabled: Bool = true
    /// The inset (spacing) at the top for the cards. Default is 40.
    @IBInspectable public var topInset: CGFloat = 40 {
        didSet {
            setCardSwiperInsets()
        }
    }
    /// The inset (spacing) at each side of the cards. Default is 20.
    @IBInspectable public var sideInset: CGFloat = 20 {
        didSet {
            setCardSwiperInsets()
        }
    }
    /// Sets how much of the next card should be visible. Default is 50.
    @IBInspectable public var visibleNextCardHeight: CGFloat = 50 {
        didSet {
            setCardSwiperInsets()
        }
    }
    /// Vertical spacing between CardCells. Default is 40.
    @IBInspectable public var cardSpacing: CGFloat = 40 {
        willSet {
            flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = newValue
        }
    }

    /// The transform animation that is shown on the top card when scrolling through the cards. Default is 0.05.
    @IBInspectable public var firstItemTransform: CGFloat = 0.05 {
        willSet {
            flowLayout.firstItemTransform = newValue
        }
    }

    public weak var delegate: VerticalCardSwiperDelegate?
    public weak var datasource: VerticalCardSwiperDatasource? {
        didSet{
            numberOfCards = datasource?.numberOfCards(verticalCardSwiperView: self.verticalCardSwiperView) ?? 0
        }
    }

    /// The amount of cards in the collectionView.
    fileprivate var numberOfCards: Int = 0
    /// We use this horizontalPangestureRecognizer for the vertical panning.
    fileprivate var horizontalPangestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    /// Stores a `CGRect` with the area that is swipeable to the user.
    fileprivate var swipeAbleArea: CGRect!
    /// The `CardCell` that the user can (and is) moving.
    fileprivate var swipedCard: CardCell! {
        didSet {
            setupCardSwipeDelegate()
        }
    }

    /// The flowlayout used in the collectionView.
    fileprivate lazy var flowLayout: VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout = {
        let flowLayout = VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.firstItemTransform = firstItemTransform
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = cardSpacing
        flowLayout.isPagingEnabled = true
        return flowLayout
    }()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        commonInit()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    fileprivate func commonInit() {

        setupVerticalCardSwiperView()
        setupConstraints()
        setCardSwiperInsets()
        setupGestureRecognizer()
    }
}

extension VerticalCardSwiper: CardDelegate {

    internal func willSwipeAway(cell: CardCell, swipeDirection: SwipeDirection) {

        verticalCardSwiperView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        if let index = verticalCardSwiperView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row {
            self.delegate?.willSwipeCardAway?(card: cell, index: index, swipeDirection: swipeDirection)
        }
    }

    internal func didSwipeAway(cell: CardCell, swipeDirection direction: SwipeDirection) {

        if let indexPathToRemove = verticalCardSwiperView.indexPath(for: cell){

            self.numberOfCards -= 1
            swipedCard = nil

            self.verticalCardSwiperView.performBatchUpdates({
                self.verticalCardSwiperView.deleteItems(at: [indexPathToRemove])
            }) { [weak self] (finished) in
                if finished {
                    self?.verticalCardSwiperView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                    self?.verticalCardSwiperView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self?.delegate?.didSwipeCardAway?(card: cell, index: indexPathToRemove.row ,swipeDirection: direction)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal func didDragCard(cell: CardCell, swipeDirection: SwipeDirection) {

        if let index = verticalCardSwiperView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row {
            self.delegate?.didDragCard?(card: cell, index: index, swipeDirection: swipeDirection)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupCardSwipeDelegate() {
        swipedCard?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension VerticalCardSwiper: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        if let panGestureRec = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {

            // When a horizontal pan is detected, we make sure to disable the collectionView.panGestureRecognizer so that it doesn't interfere with the sideswipe.
            if panGestureRec == horizontalPangestureRecognizer, panGestureRec.direction!.isX {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    /// We set up the `horizontalPangestureRecognizer` and attach it to the `collectionView`.
    fileprivate func setupGestureRecognizer(){

        horizontalPangestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        horizontalPangestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        horizontalPangestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        verticalCardSwiperView.addGestureRecognizer(horizontalPangestureRecognizer)
        verticalCardSwiperView.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    }

    /**
     This function is called when a pan is detected inside the `collectionView`.
     We also take care of detecting if the pan gesture is inside the `swipeAbleArea` and we animate the cell if necessary.
     - parameter sender: The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that detects the pan gesture. In this case `horizontalPangestureRecognizer`.
     */
    @objc fileprivate func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        guard isSideSwipingEnabled else {
            return
        }

        /// The taplocation relative to the superview.
        let location = sender.location(in: self)
        /// The taplocation relative to the collectionView.
        let locationInCollectionView = sender.location(in: verticalCardSwiperView)
        /// The translation of the finger performing the PanGesture.
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self)

        if swipeAbleArea.contains(location) && !verticalCardSwiperView.isScrolling {
            if let swipedCardIndex = verticalCardSwiperView.indexPathForItem(at: locationInCollectionView) {
                /// The card that is swipeable inside the SwipeAbleArea.
                swipedCard = verticalCardSwiperView.cellForItem(at: swipedCardIndex) as? CardCell
            }
        }

        if swipedCard != nil && !verticalCardSwiperView.isScrolling {

            /// The angle we pass for the swipe animation.
            let maximumRotation: CGFloat = 1.0
            let rotationStrength = min(translation.x/swipedCard.frame.width, maximumRotation)
            let angle = (CGFloat.pi/10.0) * rotationStrength

            switch (sender.state) {

            case .began:
                break

            case .changed:
                swipedCard.animateCard(angle: angle, horizontalTranslation: translation.x)
                break

            case .ended:
                swipedCard.endedPanAnimation(angle: angle)
                swipedCard = nil
                break

            default:
                swipedCard.resetToCenterPosition()
                swipedCard = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

extension VerticalCardSwiper: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    /**
     Reloads all of the data for the VerticalCardSwiperView.

     Call this method sparingly when you need to reload all of the items in the VerticalCardSwiper. This causes the VerticalCardSwiperView to discard any currently visible items (including placeholders) and recreate items based on the current state of the data source object. For efficiency, the VerticalCardSwiperView only displays those cells and supplementary views that are visible. If the data shrinks as a result of the reload, the VerticalCardSwiperView adjusts its scrolling offsets accordingly.
    */
    public func reloadData(){
        verticalCardSwiperView.reloadData()
    }

    /**
     Register a class for use in creating new CardCells.
     Prior to calling the dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:) method of the collection view,
     you must use this method or the register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:) method
     to tell the collection view how to create a new cell of the given type.
     If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue,
     the VerticalCardSwiper uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.
     If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier,
     the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces the old entry.
     You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.
     - parameter cellClass: The class of a cell that you want to use in the VerticalCardSwiper
     identifier
     - parameter identifier: The reuse identifier to associate with the specified class. This parameter must not be nil and must not be an empty string.
     */
    public func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        verticalCardSwiperView.register(cellClass, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    /**
     Register a nib file for use in creating new collection view cells.
     Prior to calling the dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:) method of the collection view,
     you must use this method or the register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:) method
     to tell the collection view how to create a new cell of the given type.
     If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue,
     the collection view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.
     If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier,
     the object you specify in the nib parameter replaces the old entry.
     You may specify nil for nib if you want to unregister the nib file from the specified reuse identifier.
     - parameter nib: The nib object containing the cell object. The nib file must contain only one top-level object and that object must be of the type UICollectionViewCell.
     identifier
     - parameter identifier: The reuse identifier to associate with the specified nib file. This parameter must not be nil and must not be an empty string.
    */
    public func register(nib: UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        verticalCardSwiperView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.numberOfCards
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        return (datasource?.cardForItemAt(verticalCardSwiperView: verticalCardSwiperView, cardForItemAt: indexPath.row))!
    }

    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        delegate?.didScroll?(verticalCardSwiperView: verticalCardSwiperView)
    }

    fileprivate func setupVerticalCardSwiperView(){

        verticalCardSwiperView = VerticalCardSwiperView(frame: self.frame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        verticalCardSwiperView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
        verticalCardSwiperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        verticalCardSwiperView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        verticalCardSwiperView.delegate = self
        verticalCardSwiperView.dataSource = self

        self.numberOfCards = datasource?.numberOfCards(verticalCardSwiperView: verticalCardSwiperView) ?? 0

        self.addSubview(verticalCardSwiperView)
    }

    fileprivate func setupConstraints(){

        verticalCardSwiperView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            verticalCardSwiperView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            verticalCardSwiperView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            verticalCardSwiperView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            verticalCardSwiperView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }

    fileprivate func setCardSwiperInsets(){

        verticalCardSwiperView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: sideInset, bottom: topInset + flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing + visibleNextCardHeight, right: sideInset)
    }
}

extension VerticalCardSwiper: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let itemSize = calculateItemSize(for: indexPath.row)

        // set cellHeight in the custom flowlayout, we use this for paging calculations.
        flowLayout.cellHeight = itemSize.height

        if swipeAbleArea == nil {
            // Calculate and set the swipeAbleArea. We use this to determine wheter the cell can be swiped to the sides or not.
            let swipeAbleAreaOriginY = collectionView.frame.origin.y + collectionView.contentInset.top
            swipeAbleArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: swipeAbleAreaOriginY, width: self.frame.width, height: itemSize.height)
        }
        return itemSize
    }

    fileprivate func calculateItemSize(for index: Int) -> CGSize {

        let cellWidth: CGFloat!
        let cellHeight: CGFloat!
        let xInsets = sideInset * 2
        let yInsets = cardSpacing + visibleNextCardHeight + topInset

        // get size from delegate if the sizeForItem function is called.
        if let customSize = delegate?.sizeForItem?(verticalCardSwiperView: verticalCardSwiperView, index: index) {
            // set custom sizes and make sure sizes are not negative, if they are, don't subtract the insets.
            cellWidth = customSize.width - (customSize.width - xInsets > 0 ? xInsets : 0)
            cellHeight = customSize.height - (customSize.height - yInsets > 0 ? yInsets : 0)
        } else {
            cellWidth = verticalCardSwiperView.frame.size.width - xInsets
            cellHeight = verticalCardSwiperView.frame.size.height - yInsets
        }
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }
}
```

Custom FlowLayout:

```
import UIKit

/// Custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that provides the flowlayout information like paging and `CardCell` movements.
internal class VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    /// This property sets the amount of scaling for the first item.
    internal var firstItemTransform: CGFloat?
    /// This property enables paging per card. The default value is true.
    internal var isPagingEnabled: Bool = true
    /// Stores the height of a CardCell.
    internal var cellHeight: CGFloat!

    internal override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        assert(collectionView!.numberOfSections == 1, "Number of sections should always be 1.")
        assert(collectionView!.isPagingEnabled == false, "Paging on the collectionview itself should never be enabled. To enable cell paging, use the isPagingEnabled property of the VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout instead.")
    }

    internal override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let items = NSArray (array: super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!, copyItems: true)

        items.enumerateObjects(using: { (object, index, stop) -> Void in
            let attributes = object as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

            self.updateCellAttributes(attributes)
        })
        return items as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    }

    // We invalidate the layout when a "bounds change" happens, for example when we scale the top cell. This forces a layout update on the flowlayout.
    internal override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Cell paging
    internal override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        // If the property `isPagingEnabled` is set to false, we don't enable paging and thus return the current contentoffset.
        guard isPagingEnabled else {
            let latestOffset = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
            return latestOffset
        }

        // Page height used for estimating and calculating paging.
        let pageHeight = cellHeight + self.minimumLineSpacing

        // Make an estimation of the current page position.
        let approximatePage = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y/pageHeight

        // Determine the current page based on velocity.
        let currentPage = (velocity.y < 0.0) ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage)

        // Create custom flickVelocity.
        let flickVelocity = velocity.y * 0.3

        // Check how many pages the user flicked, if <= 1 then flickedPages should return 0.
        let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)

        // Calculate newVerticalOffset.
        let newVerticalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * pageHeight) - self.collectionView!.contentInset.top

        return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: newVerticalOffset)
    }

    internal override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        // make sure the zIndex of the next card is higher than the one we're swiping away.
        let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndexPath.row + 1, section: itemIndexPath.section)
        let nextAttr = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: nextIndexPath)
        nextAttr?.zIndex = nextIndexPath.row

        // attributes for swiping card away
        let attr = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: itemIndexPath)

        return attr
    }

    /**
     Updates the attributes.
     Here manipulate the zIndex of the cards here, calculate the positions and do the animations.
     - parameter attributes: The attributes we're updating.
     */
    fileprivate func updateCellAttributes(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        let minY = collectionView!.bounds.minY + collectionView!.contentInset.top
        let maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y

        let finalY = max(minY, maxY)
        var origin = attributes.frame.origin
        let deltaY = (finalY - origin.y) / attributes.frame.height

        if let itemTransform = firstItemTransform {
            let scale = 1 - deltaY * itemTransform
            attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            // TODO: add card stack effect (like Shazam)
        }
        origin.y = finalY
        attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: attributes.frame.size)
        attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
    }
}
```

CardCell code (subclass of UICollectionViewCell):

```
import UIKit

/**
 The CardCell that the user can swipe away. Based on `UICollectionViewCell`.

 The cells will be recycled by the `VerticalCardSwiper`,
 so don't forget to override `prepareForReuse` when needed.
 */
@objc open class CardCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    internal weak var delegate: CardDelegate?

    open override func layoutSubviews() {

        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    open override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        super.apply(layoutAttributes)

        self.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(layoutAttributes.zIndex)
    }

    open override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        // need to unhide a cell for reuse (cell is hidden when swiped away)
        self.isHidden = false
    }

    /**
     This function animates the card. The animation consists of a rotation and translation.
     - parameter angle: The angle the card rotates while animating.
     - parameter horizontalTranslation: The horizontal translation the card animates in.
     */
    public func animateCard(angle: CGFloat, horizontalTranslation: CGFloat){

        delegate?.didDragCard(cell: self, swipeDirection: determineCardSwipeDirection())

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 0, 1)
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, horizontalTranslation, 0, 1)

        self.layer.transform = transform
    }

    /**
     Resets the CardCell back to the center of the VerticalCardSwiperView.
     */
    public func resetToCenterPosition(){

        let cardCenterX = self.frame.midX
        let centerX = self.bounds.midX
        let initialSpringVelocity = fabs(cardCenterX - centerX)/100

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
                       initialSpringVelocity: initialSpringVelocity,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        self?.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })
    }

    /**
     Called when the pan gesture is ended.
     Handles what happens when the user stops swiping a card.
     If a certain treshold of the screen is swiped, the `animateOffScreen` function is called,
     if the threshold is not reached, the card will be reset to the center by calling `resetToCenterPosition`.
     - parameter angle: The angle of the animation, depends on the direction of the swipe.
     */
    internal func endedPanAnimation(angle: CGFloat){

        let swipePercentageMargin = self.bounds.width * 0.4
        let cardCenterX = self.frame.midX
        let centerX = self.bounds.midX

        // check for left or right swipe and if swipePercentageMargin is reached or not
        if (cardCenterX < centerX - swipePercentageMargin || cardCenterX > centerX + swipePercentageMargin){
            animateOffScreen(angle: angle)
        } else {
            self.resetToCenterPosition()
        }
    }

    /**
     Animates to card off the screen and calls the `willSwipeAway` and `didSwipeAway` functions from the `CardDelegate`.
     - parameter angle: The angle that the card will rotate in (depends on direction). Positive means the card is swiped to the right, a negative angle means the card is swiped to the left.
     */
    fileprivate func animateOffScreen(angle: CGFloat){

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        let direction = determineCardSwipeDirection()

        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 0, 1)

        switch direction {

        case .Left:

            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -(self.frame.width * 2), 0, 1)
            break

        case .Right:

            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, (self.frame.width * 2), 0, 1)
            break

        default: break

        }

        self.delegate?.willSwipeAway(cell: self, swipeDirection: direction)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.layer.transform = transform
        }){ (completed) in
            self.isHidden = true
            self.delegate?.didSwipeAway(cell: self, swipeDirection: direction)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func determineCardSwipeDirection() -> SwipeDirection {

        let cardCenterX = self.frame.midX
        let centerX = self.bounds.midX

        if cardCenterX < centerX {
            return .Left
        } else if cardCenterX > centerX {
            return .Right
        } else {
            return .None
        }
    }
}
```

**You can find it on github:**
[VerticalCardSwiper](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper)

Let me know if you want any more code in this answer, then I'll add it, but it's a lot so might be easier to visit the repo.

Comment: awesome bro 

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement swipe gesture and scrollView. It can be tricky in few cases, setting below condition will help

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(< UISwipeGestureRecognizer instance>)
```

Refer this for better understanding:

[how-to-recognize-swipe-gesture-in-uiscrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648967/how-to-recognize-swipe-gesture-in-uiscrollview)